# Trace 'Accept' system call with eBPF and calculate the wallclock time between 'accept' and 'close' of a PID

Tags: c, ebpf, bpf, libbpf

I am trying to measure the time it takes for a particular process to accept a connection using the 'accept' system call and close the connection. To accomplish this, I want to use eBPF to trace the 'accept' system call and calculate the wallclock time between 'accept' and 'close' of a specific process ID (PID).

```c
#include "vmlinux.h"
#include <bpf/bpf_helpers.h>
#include <bpf/bpf_tracing.h>
#include <bpf/bpf_core_read.h>
// #include "net/sock.h"
char LICENSE[] SEC("license") = "Dual BSD/GPL";


struct {
    __uint(type, BPF_MAP_TYPE_HASH);
    __uint(max_entries, 8192);
    __type(key, int);
    __type(value, int);
} pid_map SEC(".maps");

u64 get_current_time(){
    u64 ts = bpf_ktime_get_ns();
    return ts;
}

SEC("kprobe/tcp_v4_do_rcv")
int bpf_prog(struct pt_regs *ctx)
{
    int pid = bpf_get_current_pid_tgid() >> 32;
    u64 start_time = get_current_time();
    bpf_printk("BPF triggered from PID %d.\n", pid);
    bpf_map_update_elem(&pid_map, &pid,&start_time, BPF_ANY);
    return 0;
}
```

BPF code for this is shown above,

```c
SEC("kprobe/tcp_close")
int bpf_prog2(struct pt_regs *ctx)
{
    int pid = bpf_get_current_pid_tgid() >> 32;
    u64 *pid_ptr = bpf_map_lookup_elem(&pid_map, &pid);
    
    if (pid_ptr != NULL && *pid_ptr == pid && *pid_ptr>100ULL) {
        bpf_printk("Process closed connection %d\n: ",pid);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

And I also wrote simple python script to open and close a port

```py
import socket

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)


s.connect(('www.google.com', 80))


s.send(b"GET / HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: www.google.com\r\n\r\n")


response = s.recv(1024)
print(response)


s.close()
```

Unfortunately I couldnt get any response.

Trie the following types to for accept

```c
// SEC("kprobe/tcp_v4_do_rcv")
// SEC("kprobe/__x64_sys_accept")
// SEC("kprobe/tcp_v4_do_rcv")
// SEC("kprobe/inet_csk_accept")
```

and for close()

```c
// SEC("kprobe/tcp_v6_destroy_sock")
// SEC("kprobe/tcp_v4_destroy_sock")
```

Comment: `kprobe/__x64_sys_accept` looks like the only potentially correct hook point here. Did you trace your small example program to verify that it's actually calling the `accept(2)` syscall?

Comment: Thanks for your comment. kprobe/__x64_sys_accept did work for connection through the lo interface. After some trial and error, I can now trace all TCP  accept connections wth kretprobe/tcp_v4_connect and close with kprobe/tcp_close.